# How to resolve deprecation warning in pytest

Tags: python, pyspark, pytest

Below is the pytest code I am using:

```
from config import BatchId
from util import readParquetFiles,startSparkSession
import pytest     
pytest.x = 100
pytest.spark =   startSparkSession()    
pytest.path = "D:\\filepath\\"

class TestStringMethods:         

    @pytest.mark.order1
    def test_one(self): 
        print("\nthis is first")        
        pytest.x=BatchId          

    @pytest.mark.order2
    def test_two(self):       
        print("\nthis is second")

    @pytest.mark.order3
    def test_three(self): 
        df= readParquetFiles(pytest.spark,pytest.path)
        print("df.count {}: ".format(df.count()))
```

readParquetFiles is a method in util.py

```
def readParquetFiles(spark,pathToLoad):
    parquetFiles = [f for f in glob.glob(pathToLoad + "**/*.parquet", recursive=True)]
    parquetDF = spark.read.load(parquetFiles)
    return parquetDF;
```

When i execute this code i am getting below warnings:

```
DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working

======================================== 3 passed, 6 warnings in 6.96 seconds =========================================
```

I am new to pytest and couldn't find a solution to this problem. Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here. I know this is something to so with the third test case because when i remove that first two works fine.

Comment: Some detail on the warning [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/5460). Might be due to some module you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't updated your python, then try running the program with `python2`. This may or may not work depending on how old the program is.

Comment: I am using python 3.7. Can you tell me why i am getting this error or is this a bug in pytest?